# What will the underlying group of a field be isomorphic to?

Tags: field-theory

Let $(F,+,.)$ be a finite field with 9 elements. Let $G=(F,+)$ and $H=(F\setminus \{0\},.)$ denote the underlying additive and multiplicative groups. Then what will $G$ and $H$ be isomorphic to?

We know that any finte abelian group is a direct product of cyclic group thus either $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_9$ or $\mathbb Z_3\times \mathbb Z_3$ and $H$ is isomorphic to either $\mathbb Z_8$ or $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$. Since a field can have no zero divisor theus $G$ willbe isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_3\times \mathbb Z_3$

But I can't conclude what $H$ will be isomorphic to. Any help

Comment: Amazingly, $H$ is always cyclic.  And $G$ is always a direct sum of cyclics.

Comment: See here, for example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837562/why-is-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-finite-field-cyclic

Comment: What I'm trying to say is $H$ is cyclic no matter what $F$ is, as long as it is a finite field.  Most people find that fact pretty startling.

Comment: In principle, $H$  could also be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually *any*  finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field (whether the field itself is finite or not) is cyclic. In the present case, 
$$\mathbf F_9^{\times}\simeq \mathbf Z/8\mathbf Z$$

Comment: Asimple question sir ...Why?

Comment: @learnmore: see my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198533/if-g-is-a-finite-group-of-anyone-of-the-multiplicative-non-zero-elements-of-q-r/1198742#1198742).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an elementary argument that does not even need the structure theorem of abelian groups:

Let $n$ be the exponent of $H$, that is, the smallest $n$ such that $h^n=1$ for all $h\in H$.

By Lagrange's theorem, $n\le 8$.

If $n<8$, then equation $x^n=1$ would have $8$ solutions, and this cannot happen in a field.

Hence, $n=8$.

If all elements have order less than $8$, then the exponent is at most $4$, because the possible orders are $1$, $2$, or $4$.

Since the exponent is $8$, $H$ must then have an element of order $8$ and so $H$ is cyclic.

Comment: what is exponent?

Comment: @learnmore, see my edited answer.